# how to check that pgx.Row is empty

Tags: go

I want to check if something has been returned from the database

```
rows, err := r.db.Query(r.ctx, getFilmCastQuery, FilmId)
if err == pgx.ErrNoRows {
    logs.LogError(logs.Logger, "films_postgresql", "GetFilmCast", err, err.Error())
    return nil, domain.ErrNotFound
}
```

But if I write like this, the error is always nil even if null is returned from the database

Comment: are you using 'github.com/jmoiron/sqlx'?

Answer (score 2):

`pgx.ErrNoRows` is only returned when using `QueryRow`.

The implementation is [here](https://github.com/jackc/pgx/blob/master/rows.go#L113).

The only way to handle no results found when using `Query` is to check the  slice length is equal to 0 after the `rows.Next()` loop.